# Android - How to make the XML file for a icon?

Tags: android, xml, android-vectordrawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdvWp.png)This is the xml file for the SHARE icon. How do I create XML for other icons?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportHeight="24.0"
android:viewportWidth="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M18,16.08c-0.76,0 -1.44,0.3 -1.96,0.77L8.91,12.7c0.05,-0.23 0.09,-0.46 0.09,-0.7s-0.04,-0.47 -0.09,-0.7l7.05,-4.11c0.54,0.5 1.25,0.81 2.04,0.81 1.66,0 3,-1.34 3,-3s-1.34,-3 -3,-3 -3,1.34 -3,3c0,0.24 0.04,0.47 0.09,0.7L8.04,9.81C7.5,9.31 6.79,9 6,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3c0.79,0 1.5,-0.31 2.04,-0.81l7.12,4.16c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.61 1.31,2.92 2.92,2.92 1.61,0 2.92,-1.31 2.92,-2.92s-1.31,-2.92 -2.92,-2.92z" />
```

Comment: and not getting anything.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If you're using an up to date version of Android Studio then right click on your drawable folder.
Go to New > Vector Asset. This opens the Vector Asset Studio.

From here you can either select from a wide range of provided Material Design icons, or import your own svg if you want to.(importing an svg might not work properly in all cases)

Comment: is there any difference between svg  and png ?

Comment: It's an incredible feature, thank you! I didn't know about it before

Comment: How would I make an XML icon from scratch?

Comment: Two warnings: 
1 - Android Studio only shows you your XML drawables when you switch to "Packages" view. (Drop down in the upper left corner of the Project browser sidebar.) 
2 - While in Packages view, "Vector Asset" won't be available from the "New" menu when you right-click on the drawables folder. You have to right-click on one of the items in that folder.

Answer (score 6):

Android Assets studio is not an "All in One" option as it misses many basic icons like that of google, LinkedIn etc even in the new version Android Studio, so for missing icons, a simple way would be to first download your desired image in `SVG format`, then go to `drawable>New>Vector Asset` and select `Local file(SVG, PSD)`, locate your SVG File and click `Next>Finish`.

Now that file is converted into an `XML File`, very easy, you can now change its colors/size also in code of XML.

Comment: I wonder how long android (google) is waiting to support SVG.

Answer (score 0):

The Easier Way would be to right click on drawable -> New-> Vector Image Asset then download your desired Icon, After Downloading open the xml file and change the color to white.YOU MIGHT WANT TO RENAME FROM BLACK

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps you can follow (it worked for me):

- Create 2 images for foreground and background (for ex. in draw.io) and export each image as SVG (name them as `background.svg` and `foreground.svg`).  I created 2 images of 1" X 1".
- Now, you can follow this tutorial : https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-change-app-icon.  Use the `background.svg` and `foreground.svg` images you exported above instead of the ones provided in the tutorial.